# Sharepoint list views not consitent

Tags: list, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-list

I have a sharepoint site with a permission level called 'user' which has the below all unticked

*Manage Lists  -  Create and delete lists, add or remove columns in a list, and add or remove public views of a list.
Manage Personal Views  -  Create, change, and delete personal views of lists.
Add/Remove Personal Web Parts  -  Add or remove personal Web Parts on a Web Part Page.
Update Personal Web Parts  -  Update Web Parts to display personalized information.*

On one list, it has two views.  One of the views says show everything (an admin view, shouldn't be available) and the other only shows available to that user.  A user who has this permission can open the list but only has 1 of the 2 views set up available.

On another list, with the same permissions, the user can see both the admin view and the 'public' view.

I am trying to prevent users from selecting anything bar the default view on either list, and it seems on one list it works as intended and the other it does not despite consistent permissions etc

Comment: Check that the non-visible view is a personal view, not a public view. If all else fails, delete the view and create it again from scratch with the account that you want to make it visible to, and make sure to tick the box for personal view..

Comment: What is the version of SharePoint? Per my knowledge, without Manage Lists permission, users can see the view nut cannot manage the view.